# Showing the sets are equivalent using set builder notation.

Tags: proof-verification

Proof: Just observe the following sequence of equalities. 
   \begin{align*}
   A  \times  (B - C)&=\{(x,y):(x\in A)\land(y\in(B-C))\} \textbf{(def. of $\times$)} \\
   &=\{(x,y):(x\in A)\land (y\in B)\land(y\notin C)\} \textbf{(def. of -)} \\
   &=\{(x,y):(x\in A)\land(x\in A)\land (y\in B)\land(y\notin C)\} \textbf{(P=$P\land P$)} \\
   &=\{(x,y):((x\in A)\land (y\in B))\land((x\in A)\land(y\notin C))\}\textbf{(rearrange)} \\
   &=\{(x,y):(x\in A)\land (y\in B)\}\cap\{(x,y):(x\in A)\land(y\notin C)\}\textbf{(def. of $\cap$)} \\
   &=\{(x,y):(x\in A)\land (y\in B)\}-\{(x,y):(x\in A)\land(y\notin C)\}\textbf{(Basic properties of $\cap$)} \\
   &=(A  \times  B) - (A  \times  C)\textbf{(def. of $\times$)}
   \end{align*}

The last two lines is wrong but I don't know how to arrive at that part.

Comment: $\{(x,y):(x\in A)\land (y\in B)\}\cap\{(x,y):(x\in A)\land(y\notin C)\} =\{(x,y):(x\in A)\land (y\in B)\}-\{(x,y):(x\in A)\land(y\in C)\}$

Comment: I don't follow the - - from the intersection

Comment: Look only at $y.$ So, $y\in B\cap \bar{C} \iff y\in B, y\notin C \iff y\in B\setminus C.$